# company-mode in shell-mode doesn't complete ./executables

Tags: company-mode, shell-mode

With company-mode on in shell-mode, if I'm in ~/bin I can get completions if I type `~/bin/someprog` or even `../bin/someprog` but not `./someprog` – is there some setting to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the reason: https://stackoverflow.com/a/220960/69663
A `M-x shell-resync-dirs` after using [fasd](https://github.com/clvv/fasd) to change dirs fixes it. It'd be nice if `comint-dynamic-complete-filename` or what it is could simply check `/proc/$$/cwd` instead …